# static amount not variable

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments, node-modules

how can i send variable amount on my line item as it only accept integers please rest everything works but this varible amount is not working tried $params->amount not working

```html
<?php

require_once('vendor/autoload.php');
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey('sk_test_key');

$session = \Stripe\Checkout\Session::create([
    'payment_method_types' => ['card'],
    'line_items' => [[
      'price_data' => [
        'currency' => 'usd',
        'product_data' => [
          'name' => 'T-shirt',
        ],
        'unit_amount' => 2000,
      ],
      'quantity' => 1,
    ]],
    'mode' => 'payment',
    'success_url' => 'https://example.com/success',
    'cancel_url' => 'https://example.com/cancel',
  ]);

?>

<html>
  <head>
    <title>Buy cool new product</title>
    <script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
      <div class="field">

      <label for="amount">Amount to pay</label>
      <input type="number" id="amount" step="0.01" value="5.00">
      </div>
      <button id="checkout-button">Checkout</button>
      <script>
          var stripe = Stripe('pk_test_51JWkHLK7X12cK8Ptf5y5DQn6Ugf6miu3AqSuhH9wdLsyTB9ouf0TY31vDQxq19xIt6YH76uMTEX1kU9HMyrcEb6w00MTxHnGxc');
          var amount = document.getElementById('amount');
          const btn = document.getElementById("checkout-button")
          btn.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
              e.preventDefault();
              stripe.redirectToCheckout({
                sessionId: "<?php echo $session->id; ?>"            
          });
          })
          
      </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

how can i send variable amount on my line item as it only accept integers please rest everything works but this varible amount is not working tried $params->amount not working

Comment: You included your secret key in the second snippet, you should remove that and roll the key in your dashboard.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [stripe online payment intent client secret](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69416575/stripe-online-payment-intent-client-secret)

Answer (score 0):

The code to create the payment intent with your secret key needs to be run server-side - you must not use your secret key in client-side code.

You should follow the guide [here](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=web&ui=elements#web-create-payment-intent) to see how you can generate a payment intent and provide the secret key in a server rendered template, or you can make an async request to your server from an SPA to get a payment intent client secret. The guide goes through both options.

Comment: i dont have any server so i was assuming icould use secound diagram withouth server one

Comment: i am having my website using website builder of odaddy on that i can only input custom code not foles

Comment: i saw one video online that guy used this method but his method was for php i need node so that i can create a single file to submit on my website section https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oFu9dLqnypU&list=WL&index=74

Comment: if I am missing something pls enlighten me. i don't have a server as they are way too expensive around 2000$ here in Dubai. if there is a way around it without a server will be thankfull

Comment: if anthing like where i can use keys but it dosent show in log some sort of code

Comment: even though keys are visible but this things still dosent work why

Comment: As written, your confirmCardPayment call uses the placeholder client secret instead of substituting the real one from a payment intent you create, other issues aside. You cannot build a custom payment flow integration without a back end server. If you do not have a server, you should consider using Payment Links instead, or look at various plugin options.

Comment: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-links
https://stripe.com/en-ca/partners/apps-and-extensions?q=plugin

Comment: Can we use ftp as backend server?

Comment: Or if i make another website that include files on it and use it as server is this possible, sorry in advance for asking such foolish questions if it is, any solution for back end server. I am starting up small business which requires online payment so if stripe cant help any other suggestions like other payment gateway that dosent require server or backend?

Comment: I don't think that would be a good idea, no. But now you're asking a different question about how to host an application, which is covered many other resources.

Comment: You can use Stripe, just not a *custom* payment flow. Look at the Payment Links docs above, Payment Links can do this for you with no server.

Comment: Sorry once again for disturbing and asking irrelevant questions, if let say i use stripe as plug ins into woocommerce and wordpress will i be able to setup dynamic pricing based on selection